# How to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} x \arctan(nx)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

How should I solve the limit for this function? Can I simply substitute $\arctan(nx)$ with $nx$ ( as they are equivalent)? That would be too easy, so, how should I do it? If $x=0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x \arctan(nx)=0$, if $x \rightarrow \infty$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}x  \arctan(nx) = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Again this seems too vague to be true reasoning, so how could I do it?

Comment: They are equivalent near zero, not near infinity !

Comment: You should try plotting it for a few values of $n$ first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=0$, the limit is zero.

If $ x>0$, then $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\arctan(nx)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}x\arctan(nx)=\frac{\pi x}{2}$$

If $ x<0 $, the limit will be $$-\frac{\pi x}{2}$$

We can resume this by
$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R) \;\; \lim_{n\to+\infty}x\arctan(nx)=\frac{\pi}{2}|x|$$